# Display child posts on parent post page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I wasted a lot of time trying to show child post on parent post page in WordPress but I did not find a solution

One of my attempts :

```
<?php
    $children = array( 
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(); 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $children );
    if($query->have_posts()) : 
        
                while($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                   echo the_title();
                }
        ?>
```

the result in page : All page content has disappeared
so where is my mistake to have this result ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'custom-post-type-name',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );

    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : 
           $parent->the_post(); 
?>
            <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page">
                <h1>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
<?php
        endwhile; 

    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).